# D3Js.v5: ...selectAll(...).data(...).enter is not a function

Tags: d3.js

I'm learning D3 JS, and I'm trying to replicate the D3 bar chart tutorial [here](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/7341714). It works as is using d3.v3, but the moment I change the src to d3.d5 by changing:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>
//Irrelevant CSS...
</style>
<svg class="chart"></svg>

<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script> //Changed to d3.v5
<script>

var width = 420,
    barHeight = 20;

var x = d3.scale.linear()
    .range([0, width]);

var chart = d3.select(".chart")
    .attr("width", width);

d3.tsv("data.tsv", type, function(error, data) {
  x.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.value; })]);

  chart.attr("height", barHeight * data.length);

  var bar = chart.selectAll("g")
      .data(data)
    .enter().append("g")
      .attr("transform", function(d, i) { return "translate(0," + i * barHeight + ")"; });

  bar.append("rect")
      .attr("width", function(d) { return x(d.value); })
      .attr("height", barHeight - 1);

  bar.append("text")
      .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.value) - 3; })
      .attr("y", barHeight / 2)
      .attr("dy", ".35em")
      .text(function(d) { return d.value; });
});

function type(d) {
  d.value = +d.value; // coerce to number
  return d;
}

</script>
```

I get an error:

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: chart.selectAll(...).data(...).enter is not a function
```

I'd rather learn the latest and greatest, which I assume is D3.v5, instead of D3.v3, unless the latter really is the latest stable build. Was there a syntax change in this method chain? because I thought `.selectAll(...).data(...).enter` would be a pretty "standard" method chain. This has been surprisingly resistant to googling, unfortunately; similar problems are much more complex use-cases with many more degrees of freedom, whereas my question simply involves changing the D3 version.

Comment: If you get the error please copy/paste **your code** using v5, otherwise there is not much we can do to help you.

Comment: most likely your `data` is undefined (not loaded), and d3v5 uses Promises for loading data (different syntax/API).

Answer (score 2):

I see 2 problems with your solution:

1. Change d3.scale.linear() to d3.scaleLinear()
2. Change `d3.tsv("data.tsv", type, function(error, data) {` to `d3.tsv("data.tsv").then(function(data) {`

Explanation for 2: d3.tsv function returns a promise which needs to be resolved before you can use the data